# Animation in Swing

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer

I have a project written using Swing, and I want to make it more smoothly (like JavaFX is) by adding animation to some components(`JButton`, `JScrollPane`, `JSplitPane`) using `javax.swing.Timer`.

That is not a game. I want to use the `Timer` for short animations like mouseHover events, dropdown, or scroll. But the problem is, a lot of Timer objects should be created.

**Question:** What action does it perform for JVM? I would start and stop a lot of Timers during app session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What action does it perform for JVM? I would start and stop a lot of
>   Timers during app session.

[`Swing Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) fires `ActionEvents` at specified intervals to animate object providing function: start(), stop(), restart(), and most importantly `setDelay(int delay)` to fire successive action events in specific inerval ensuring all such event task are executed in the EDT(event dispatch thread). Waiting state of All created `Timers` are managed by a single shared thread, `TimerQueue`, created by the first `Timer` object that executes.

Handling `timer` might be tedious. Instead of writing same `Timer` handling code every time, I would go for using a library instead like [swing TimingFrameWork](https://java.net/projects/timingframework).

Comment: Your answer is good, but there is no answer on my question: `What action does it perform for JVM?` Would that `eat` a lot of RAM after hours working?

Comment: Swing timer allows to perform actions in EDT. And no it would not take memory other then the object living inside of it while it is executing a task. It follows the same rule any other thread does for objects. The periodic execution in interval of the swing timer works much like a thread sleep and wake up functionality. So when it has done an execution and goes to wait for next shedule, the used object might be garbage collected.

Comment: But `Threads` in java are not retriggerable. Once they was started, they would be in JVM memory during app session even after their finish. Isn't it bad?

Comment: Not really so. It completely depends on application design. A swing timer usually used for animating like moving an object, i would not like creating a new timer every time for next moving event, isn't it ? It will add even more complexity to handle. Every object and thread takes memory so do Timer, but we need to consider the balanced cost

Answer (score 2):

> That is not a game. I want to use the Timer for short animations like
>   mouseHover events, dropdown, or scroll. But the problem is, a lot of
>   Timer objects should be created.

- this is job only for one `Swing Timer` together with (mouseHover events, dropdown, or scroll) focus from `mouse or key_events`, `Swing Timer` has implemented `start()`, `stop()` and `restart()`, last one is important for waiting until users action ended
- logically isn't possible to generating more than one event, different situation will be in the case that there is multitouch display, and in this case is only one event important too, rest of events are directions, scalling, factor, etc...

Comment: > *logically isn't possible to generating more than one event* You mean *at the time*, right? I mean `during app session`. What would happened to my RAM?

Comment: What would happened to my RAM? ---> timer hasn't impact to JVM used memory or increasing JVM allocated memory, after all event(s) from Swing Action is/are executed, sure by assuming that those Object used for animations are stored in local variable, then there is registred increase of Java2D/Graphics(2D) objects, that are temporarilly type of and finalize()d, GC'ed

Comment: So, it is OK to use `javax.swing.Timer` for such purposes?

Comment: 1. yes for Java2D or flashing with series of Icons, 2. yes or not too for JComponents as Objects, this is very opened question for flashing with JComponents on screen, JComponents != text in JTextField or Rendering Objects in JList, JTable.... (for example, better explanations)

Comment: `Timer` uses `java Threads`. But `Threads` in java are not retriggerable. Once they was started, they would be in `JVM memory` during app session even after their finish. Isn't it bad?

Comment: no isn't bad, but they are GC'ed, not issue with that, there are three areas called timer, util.Timer, XxxExecutor, Swing Timer, you have to notify EDT by using invkoeLater() for util.Timer, XxxExecutor

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38773/discussion-between-seniorjd-and-mkorbel)